# Why is there no boost::container::queue?

Tags: c++, boost, queue

I am starting to work with Boost, and I am looking through the several libraries it holds.

I have noted that boost::container defines almost all standard containers, but not the `queue`.

I don't have found any reference to it; so I am wondering why there is only `deque`. I want to test the replacement of STL containers with boost ones, and I was told it would be possible...

Thanks in advance for any explanation on this subject.

Comment: Lot of boost things go to the std library, if they are there use the std::whatever (seems: in the case of queue the std was faster)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::queue` isn't a container, it's a wrapper.  It consumes a container and provides a non-container (simplified) interface.

The Boost version of `std::queue<T>` (which actually means `std::queue<T, std::deque<T> >`, via a default template argument) is `std::queue<T, boost::container::deque<T> >`.

Comment: Still: No boost queue, though, hinting to adaptors is nice. But, why does boost has not that adaptor?

Comment: @Dieter: One can't provide a superior/better implementation of an adaptor, when a particular implementation of the adaptor is required by the specification.  The improvements come from use of a different underlying container, as I showed.  How do you say that `std::queue<T, boost::container::deque<T> >` is "not a Boost queue"?

Comment: @Ben Voigt There is no boost:::queue besides boost::lockfree::queue (which is a different thing). std::whatever_template<boost::whatever> is not boost, though

Comment: @Dieter: I didn't say `boost::queue`, ever.  I said the Boost equivalent to `std::queue<T, std::deque<T> >` is `std::queue<T, boost::containers::dequeue<T> >`.  Do you disagree?  Saying `std::queue<T, boost::containers::dequeue<T> >` is not Boost is like saying `boost::containers::dequeue<std::string>` is not Boost.